# App not loading dependency properly from another package

Tags: meteor, meteor-packages

I'm playing a bit with Meteor and got stuck with a problem here. I'm using Meteor 1.2 btw.

I'm implementing a cardgame, so as I read over the interwebs as a good practice, I started separating my app features in packages.

I did an app-lib package to wire my dependencies. That package is then required by other packages in the app, so in the case that I have to update some package's version, it updates for all the packages that use it at once.

In this app-lib package I `api.imply()` the dependencies that I want to expose, to the other packages that use it. Right now, I have just one other package that is a `board` package that `api.use()` the `api-lib`, but I'm getting the following error on app startup:

> "Object [object Object] has no method 'helpers'"

This error goes for a Collection and has to do with the `dburles:collection-helpers` package I think.

The things I tried to solve the problem:

- Check that `app-lib` has `dburles:collection-helpers` on the `api.imply()`
- Include `dburles:collection-helpers` in the main app
- Include `dburles:collection-helpers` in the 'board' package

The problem persists. It's important to notice that before I extracted the packages, all the dependencies were in the main app and everything worked fine.

I think maybe the problem has to with some load order stuff that I'm not familiar with.

Any guesses?

Answer (score 0):

try remove the package and install it again? As far i know meteor sets the